# Chrome extension: how to constantly check URLs on new tabs and then respond with an action for certain URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

Hi—I'm not a student or a programmer by trade, but I'm trying to knock up a quick prototype to get an idea across. I've cobbled together some code from other StackOverflow questions, and I've almost got what I need, but I'm having trouble with one thing: the extension will run exactly once, but no more, until I refresh the extension via chrome://extensions. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the element of this program that listens for a new URL, but I can't figure out how to keep that element listening constantly. This code runs in background.js right now, though I've also tried it in background.html.

Basically, I'd like the extension to check the URL of a tab any time the user visits a new page (either by typing the URL herself or clicking through to one), and, if the URL appears in the plugin's internal URL list, to pop up a short notification. I have this so far:

```
// Called when the url of a tab changes.
// So we can notify users
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    '48.png',  
    'Alert!'
);
      // Called when the url of a tab changes.
      function checkForValidUrl(tab) {
        // Compare with a the URL
        if (tab.url.match(/google/)) {
          //then
          notification.show();
        }
      };
  // Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(changeInfo.status == "loading") {
        checkForValidUrl(tab);
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tabId, selectInfo){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
        checkForValidUrl(tab);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you running this in your [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html)? The background page is the only part of the chrome extension that continuously runs.

Comment: Yes, I should have noted that. It's in background.js now, though I've also tried it within background.html itself.

Comment: So what's the problem? Edit your question to include a clearer question :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to be as clear as possible with my limited knowledge. The problem is that while this code works the first time--after the extension is loaded, visiting a URL with "google" in it triggers the notification--but it never works after that, until the extension is reloaded. So I'm assuming it isn't running constantly.

Comment: You should probably add the Google-chrome-extension tag to this question - and maybe remove the plugins one.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this after hacking it around a little bit -- I don't really have the vocabulary to explain what I did but I thought I'd post the code in case someone else has the same (simple) problem later.

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
'48.png',  
'Alert!', 
'Watch out for your privacy!'
);

// Compare with the URL
if (tab.url.match(/google/)) {
    //then
notification.show();
}
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(changeInfo.status == "loading") {
        checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab);
    }
});
```

Comment: url is not there in tab object now. ie tab.url is undefined.

Comment: It works for me when code is executed in extension.